# wireshark windows - how to remote capture/analyze from a tshark or similar install?

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I would like to set up some small, low-end hardware wireshark capture points on my network.  I am hoping I can use something like command-line linux (ubuntu mini for example) to keep it light-weight.

I see that there is "tshark" which is a command line version of wireshark.

I have also found articles on using wireshark on a remote linux machine and creating an ssh connection in to the tshark machine and analyzing the capture data.

However, I would like to do the same, but I want to use the Windows version of wireshark to do the analysis.

Is this possible and what do I need to do (I am open to using something other than tshark if that helps)?

Answer (score 1):

Just use your low-end box with `tcpdump`, `tshark` or `wireshark` (the console version) and save the output to a file. Then download that file to your powerful desktop and load it up to wireshark GUI version.

Comment: I guess that works for most of my use cases, but I am also hoping for a real-time capability.   I wonder if for example I could use putty to create an ssh tunnel, or some other option?